# Does an official US Government website (e.g. house.gov) prominently posting information known to be false for several weeks violate any US laws?

Tags: internet, us-federal-government

At about 00:55 in CNN's [McCarthy still listed as speaker on House website. Correspondent has theory why](https://youtu.be/UXjXaXLrA2U?t=25) in response to the US Government website house.gov still listing Kevin McCarthy as Speaker of the House, a reporter asks another

> Is that even legal?

**Question:** Does an official US Government website (e.g. house.gov) prominently posting important government information that's known to be false for several weeks violate any US laws?

---

Screenshot as of 2023-10-20 (McCarthy was removed on 2023-10-03 per Wikipedia's [Speaker
of the United States House of Representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives) as of 2023-10-20:

> Incumbent: Vacant, (Pro tempore: Patrick McHenry)

[image: screenshot of https://house.gov/leadership 2023-10-20]

Comment: What is this theory about why it hasn't been updated for those of us who are unable to watch the video?

Comment: It is already updated to show Mike Jonson as the speaker which suggests it was a matter of no one being able to approve the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does an official US Government website (e.g. house.gov) prominently
> posting important government information that's known to be false for
> several weeks violate any US laws?

No.

Certainly not in the circumstances of this case, where the body has simply failed to update a website. No law requires the U.S. government, as a general rule, to have up to date websites.

Since this is a representation of Congress, the [Speech and Debate Clause of the U.S. Constitution](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S6-C1-3-1/ALDE_00013300/) provides a legal shield against any liability, civil or criminal.

Even if it was an agency other than Congress, intentionally posting false information isn't within any common exception to sovereign immunity. *See, e.g*., this [2005 law review article](https://digitalcommons.law.ou.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1246&context=olr).

There is no general constitutional right to have the government not post intentionally falsehoods. For example, U.S. currency says "In God We Trust", even though that is not true for many Americans.

Of course, there might be exceptions to this rule given specific facts not presented in the question.

This probably happened because there is no permanent Speaker of the House in place (as of the time I am writing this answer) and the website administration rules for the U.S. House of Representatives website probably requires a permanent Speaker of the House to approve any changes to it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it's given me a lot to think about. I continue to be amazed by just how much the US government depends on leaders with competence and integrity (rathe than a plethora of detailed laws) to actually work. Sites like federalreserve.gov and home.treasury.gov could "prank" stock markets at home and abroad with failures to update or even going beyond that, false announcements. Folks would likely loose their jobs in the process. Hopefully things like that are covered under "... might be exceptions to this rule given specific facts not presented in the question."

Comment: And yes, perhaps in the present case, there's simply nobody with authority to approve updates to the website, and I'd find that specific detail somewhat reassuring - it's not up to some IT intern to decide what gets posted there.

Comment: @uhoh "I continue to be amazed by just how much the US government depends on leaders with competence and integrity (rathe than a plethora of detailed laws)" This is even more true than you would think because a very large share detailed laws on the books about how to administer the government are not enforceable and can be ignored by government officials without legal consequences in the lion's share of cases since no one has standing to enforce those rules in court.